# C pass function call as variable

Tags: objective-c, c

This may be a rather unusual question (I'm sure the title is quite misleading), but is is somehow possible in C/Objective c, to pass an actual function call to another function, without changing the signature? Meaning that the function will be called once I try to get the value of the variable? (I've tried with function pointers, but of course for this I would need to change the signature)..

For better understanding here's a (fictional) example of what I'd like to achieve. (Note that foo has to be considered to be a private API)

```
int foo(double a) {
    print(a);
    print(a);
    print(a);
}


double globalCount = 1.0;
double count() {

    return globalCount++;

}

int main() {
    foo(globalCount());   // I know this syntax would evaluate globalCount() first...
}
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
```

If some bad voodoo could make this happen I'd be really glad...

Comment: Use a function pointer.

Comment: Let me see if I understand - the signature you want to avoid changing is the signature of `foo()`, and  you would like to call the `count()` function every time `a` is evaluated?

Comment: Exactly. I know it sounds kind of impossible. But I thought I'll give it a shot..

Comment: How is the parameter `a` in function `foo` actually used in your case? Is `foo` passing that value to some other function, similar to the `print` function you show above? If so, maybe you can look at manipulating that.

Comment: Compiler writers all over the world feel an involuntary shudder... It's worth looking at the optimized assembler generated for `foo()` to get a sense of what it would mean if this were possible. (Open the assistant editor and select "Assembly" and then "For Archiving.")

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

```
typedef double (*FUNC_PTR)(void);

void foo ( FUNC_PTR funcPtr )
{
  print( (*funcPtr)( ) );
  print( (*funcPtr)( ) );
  print( (*funcPtr)( ) );
}

double globalCount = 1.0;
double count() {
    return globalCount++;

}

int main() {
    foo( &count );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately I think you did not read the whole question. I asked for a (nasty) solution without changing the signature of foo(...) (I already considered function pointers as I wrote in the question..)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function pointer that points to a function of `double count(void)`
to declare such a function that accepts another function `double(*func)(void)` for more information about function pointer see: http://www.newty.de/fpt/intro.html#what

```
#include<stdio.h>

/*takes a pointer to function return type changed to void*/
void foo( double (*func)(void) ) {
    printf("%1.0f\n",func() );
    printf("%1.0f\n",func() );
    printf("%1.0f\n",func() );
}


double globalCount = 1.0;
double count(void) {

    return globalCount++;

}

int main() {
    foo( &count );
    return 0;  
}
```